# LWC Unit Test - is it mandatory?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

lastly i have found out that we can create jest unit test for Lightning Web Components and i have question if these test are required for production deployment?

Best Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, LWC unit tests are not mandatory to deploy code in PROD. SF never made UI tests mandatory, let it be VF, LAC and LWC.

UI tests that you write in JEST dont even run when you deploy in prod. In any case, unit tests are to give you confidence in your code and make future development easy without having to worry about the breakage of existing features. If you can , please do write Jest Unit Tests.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SFSE

Jest tests are recommended for LWC but **are not mandatory for production deployment**.

> Note that Jest tests are not saved to Salesforce server instance. They are only saved locally or in your version control system. They also run locally, independent of Salesforce.

Refer to these documentation links for more info:

[Write Jest Tests for Lightning Web Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.unit_testing_using_jest_create_tests)

[Unit Test Lightning Web Components with Jest](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/03/unit-test-lightning-web-components-with-jest.html)